# How do Shoutcast servers and clients deal with mp3 frame headers and frame dependencies?

Tags: audio, client-server, mp3, shoutcast, internet-radio

Short story:

**If I myself intend to receive and then send a Shoutcast compatible audio stream processed by my application, then how to do it properly using an mp3 (de/en)coder library? Pseudo code, or better - lame mp3 specific code would be highly appreciated.**

Long story:

More specific questions which bother me were caused by an [article about mp3](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm), which says:

> Generally, frames are independent items. Each frame has its own header
>   and audio informations. There is no file header. Therefore, you can
>   cut any part of MPEG file and play it correctly (this should be done
>   on frame boundaries but most applications will handle incorrect
>   headers). For Layer III, this is not 100% correct. Due to internal
>   data organization in MPEG version 1 Layer III files, frames are often
>   dependent of each other and they cannot be cut off just like that.

This made me wonder, how Shoutcast servers and clients deal with frame headers and frame dependencies.

Do I have to encode to constant bitrate (CBR) only, if I want to achieve maximum compatibility with the most of Shoutcast players out there?

Is the mp3 frame header used at all or the stream format is deduced from a Shoutcast protocol specific HTTP header?

Does Shoutcast protocol guarantee (or is it common good practice) to start serving mp3 stream on frame boundaries and continue to respond with chunks that are cut at frame boundaries? But what is the minimum or recommended size of a mp3 frame for streaming live audio?

How does Shoutcast deal with frame dependencies - does it do something special with mp3 encoding to ensure that the served stream does not have frames which depend on previous frames (if this is even possible)? Or maybe it ignores these dependencies on server side/client side, thus getting audio quality reduction or even artifacts?

Comment: This is an excellent question.  +1

Answer (score 1):

SHOUTcast servers do not know or care about the data being passed through them.  They send it as-is.  You can actually send arbitrary data through a SHOUTcast server, and receive it.  SHOUTcast will segment the media data wherever the buffer size falls.

It's up to the client to re-sync to the data.  It does this by locating the frame header, then being decoding.  Once the codec has enough frames to reliably play back audio, it will begin outputting raw PCM.  It's up to the codec when to decide it's safe to start playback.  Since the codec knows what it's doing in terms of decoding the media, it knows when it has sufficient data (including bit reservoirs) to begin without artifacts.  It's also worth noting that the bit reservoir cannot be carried on too far, so it doesn't take but a few frames at worst to handle it.

This is one of the reasons it's important to have a sizable buffer server-side, to flush to the clients as fast as possible on connect.  If playback is to start quickly, the codec needs more data than the current frame to begin.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. But can I just blindly pass to clients whatever came out of mp3 encoder, and even send partial frames or more than one frame in a single payload chunk, and every Shoutcast client with mp3 decoder will be able to deal with it?

Comment: @JustAMartin Yes, exactly.  It doesn't even need to be a SHOUTcast client, specifically.  Any MP3 player that can stream from HTTP will take care of it.  Also, you should note that this characteristic doesn't apply universally.  MP3 is fine.  AAC is fine when wrapped in ADTS.  Other containers such as Ogg or MKV/WebM cannot be sent this way.